# Cancelling ongoing http requests when next one is started - web app search feature

Tags: javascript, beginner, axios

This piece of code is aimed to cancel any ongoing search requests sent from the web application if next request is started, e.g. after user updates the search term.

I tested it in the final application and everything looks fine. It has already been deployed to the remote environment in our organization.

It appears to work fine, but are there any pitfalls in the code?

```
const ongoingRequests = [];
const fetchData = (text, activePage, itemsPerPage) => async dispatch => {
dispatch({ type: FETCH_ENTITIES });
const page = activePage - 1;

let response;

// cancel any ongoing search requests
if (ongoingRequests.length > 0) {
    ongoingRequests.map(x => x.cancel('next request started'));
    ongoingRequests.length = 0;
}

// start a new request
response = await (async () => {
    const cts = axios.CancelToken.source();
    ongoingRequests.push(cts);

    let path =
    text !== ''
        ? `/Search?PageNumber=${page}&PageSize=${itemsPerPage}&SearchTerm=${text}`
        : `?QueryLead=true&PageNumber=${page}&PageSize=${itemsPerPage}`;

    return axios
    .get(`${env_urls.api.entity}Entity${path}`, {
        cancelToken: cts.token,
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        if (
        typeof cts !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof cts.token !== 'undefined' &&
        typeof cts.token.reason !== 'undefined' &&
        cts.token.reason.message === 'next request started'
        ) {
            // request cancelled, everything ok
        } else {
        throw error;
        }
    });
})();

// response is undefined if the request has been cancelled
if (typeof response !== 'undefined') {
    const data = response.data;

    dispatch({ type: FETCH_ENTITIES_SUCCESS, data });
}
};
```

Comment: "Does it work as intended?" : it's up to you to tell us :]

Comment: @Calak Everything is fine when I test it in the application but maybe there is an issue that I cannot see. Like some js construct that makes no sense ;)

Comment: "Does it work as intended?" Did you test it? One of the prerequisites of posting on Code Review is that the code has to work to the best of your knowledge. Does it? You say it works in the application. Is that the final application that needs it? A test application?

Comment: @Mast I have updated the question.

Comment: When I implement this type of search functionality I usually cancel the current request when the user presses a key (on the keypress, paste events) and start a timer for a fraction of a second. I only start the request when the timer expires. That way I don't start requests while the user is still typing. I've also rarely found it unnecessary to keep an array of requests. I just keep the currently executing one if any.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewritte this piece of code:

```
.catch(error => {
    if (
    cts !== 'undefined' &&
    cts.token !== 'undefined' &&
    cts.token.reason !== 'undefined' &&
    cts.token.reason.message === 'next request started'
    ) {
    } else {
    throw error;
    }
}
```

To:

```
.catch(error => {
    if (
        typeof cts === 'undefined' ||
        typeof cts.token === 'undefined' ||
        typeof cts.token.reason === 'undefined' ||
        cts.token.reason.message !== 'next request started'
    ) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

And you can go further into the simplification using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key).

Comment: imo, you shouldn't use `typeof` you should just write it as `if (cts === undefined) || ...`

Comment: @MarcRohloff yeah, copy/paste's mistake :p Thx

Comment: This is the perfect example to use the new [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)